# awk or grep 2 words in iterations and output ine by line

Tags: awk, grep, output, line

I'm tying to search for 2 words in several iterations and make the output line by line
I have a source file like this :

```
    "Resource": [
        {
            "ID": "I8745",
            "UserName": "user1",
            "IpAddress": "10.10.10.2",
            "State": "AVAILABLE",
            },
        },
        {
            "ID": "I8746",
            "UserName": "user2",
            "IpAddress": "10.10.10.3",
            "State": "AVAILABLE",
        },
        {
            "ID": "I8747",
            "UserName": "user3",
            "IpAddress": "10.10.10.4",
            "State": "AVAILABLE",
        },
        {
        "ID": "I8748",
            "UserName": "user4",
            "IpAddress": "10.10.10.5",
            "State": "AVAILABLE",
        },
        ....
```

The expected result, should be like this:

```
"ID": "I8745", "UserName": "user1",
"ID": "I8746", "UserName": "user2",
"ID": "I8747", "UserName": "user3",
"ID": "I8748", "UserName": "user4",
....
```

How can do this with awk or grep if it's possible?

Thank you very much

Comment: You should use a proper JSON parser such as `jq`, Perl, Ruby, Python, etc

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
$ paste <(grep ID /tmp/in) <( grep user /tmp/in)  | sed 's/\ \+/ /g'
 "ID": "I8745",  "UserName": "user1",
 "ID": "I8746",  "UserName": "user2",
 "ID": "I8747",  "UserName": "user3",
 "ID": "I8748",  "UserName": "user4",
```

Paste combines 2 files side by side. In bash you can use `<(command)` as a "fake" file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have legal JSON it might be more reliable to use tool for working with JSON, but if you are strictly limited to AWK then you could harness it following way. Let `file.txt` content be

```
"Resource": [
    {
        "ID": "I8745",
        "UserName": "user1",
        "IpAddress": "10.10.10.2",
        "State": "AVAILABLE",
        },
    },
    {
        "ID": "I8746",
        "UserName": "user2",
        "IpAddress": "10.10.10.3",
        "State": "AVAILABLE",
    },
    {
        "ID": "I8747",
        "UserName": "user3",
        "IpAddress": "10.10.10.4",
        "State": "AVAILABLE",
    },
    {
    "ID": "I8748",
        "UserName": "user4",
        "IpAddress": "10.10.10.5",
        "State": "AVAILABLE",
    },
    ....
```

then

```
awk '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]*/,"")}/ID/{i=$0}/UserName/{print i,$0}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
"ID": "I8745", "UserName": "user1",
"ID": "I8746", "UserName": "user2",
"ID": "I8747", "UserName": "user3",
"ID": "I8748", "UserName": "user4",
```

Explanation: I use `sub` function to remove leading whitespaces, then if line contains `ID` I store whole line in variable `i`, if line contains `UserName` I `print` what is stored inside variable followed by current line. **Disclaimer**: I tested it only with your sample input, please test that code with all possible inputs.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: assumes order in json output. no bueno.

Answer (score 0):

Sed variant:

```
$ sed -n 's/[[:space:]]*//;/ID/N;s/\n[[:space:]]*/ /gp' file
"ID": "I8745", "UserName": "user1",
"ID": "I8746", "UserName": "user2",
"ID": "I8747", "UserName": "user3",
"ID": "I8748", "UserName": "user4",
```

Comment: Aren't you assuming that the keys are printed in a specific order? as in UserName on next line after ID? That's by no means the norm with json ;)